# getfulltext search result for maximum values

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 column. "Name","Address","Description".I have 100 records in it.I am writing a code for search and using getfulltext.I want to get result the maximum number search keywords records should be present to top and so on and i want to fetch all column data also.How will i improve my query.
Thanks

I am writing query like below...

mysql_query("SELECT  * from `table` WHERE MATCH(name,address,description) AGAINST ('".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

Comment: can you enhance your question? what is getfultext ? Is a programming specific function ? User defined function ?

Comment: mysql_query("SELECT  * WHERE MATCH(name,address,description) AGAINST ('".mysql_real_escape_string($search_text)."' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this trick to get a simple count of keyword

```
select
  *
from your_table 
where 
  match(name,address,description) against ($search_string IN BOOLEAN MODE)
order by
  length(concat(name,address,description))-
  length(replace(concat(name,address,description), $search_string, ''))
  /length($search_string)
  desc;
```